# how to detect disconnection in IOCP server using zero byte recv

Tags: sockets, server, iocp

I'm currently implementing IOCP server for a game and I'm trying zero bytes recv technic.

I have 3 questions.

1. If you know disconnection from the client by checking if `bytestransferred` is 0, then how do you distinguish between receive completion and disconnection?
2. I'm not performing non-block mode `recv()` when I process actual receive process because clients send the bytes of actual data first, so I know how many bytes I'm receiving. Do I need to use non-block mode `recv()` still?

I'm doing it like so.

```
InputMemoryBitStream incomming;
std::string data;
uint32_t strLen = 0;

recv(socket, reinterpret_cast<char*>(&strLen), sizeof(uint32_t), 0);
incomming.resize(strLen);
recv(socket, reinterpret_cast<char*>(incomming.getBufferPtr()), strLen, 0);
incomming.read(data, strLen);
```

(InputMemoryBitStream is for reading compressed data.)

3. I'm dynamically allocating `per io data` every time I do `WSARecv()` and `WSASend()` and I free them as soon as I finish processing completed I/Os. Is it inefficient to do that? or is it acceptable? Should I reuse `per io data` maybe?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: When performing an IOCP request, you can pass context information inside your `OVERLAPPED` struct. You can use that to flag your requests. When receiving completion notifications, you will know which type of request is notifying you and can act accordingly (ie, ignore `BytesTransferred` for zero-byte recvs)

Comment: exist sense everywhere use asynchronous I/O. so never use blocking calls like `recv`. and for what you use zero bytes recv - i think bettwer always pass not empty buffer for recv. and when you receive 0 bytes - you know that disconnect happens